# How do I get PubNub to remember my last states and amalgamate them?

Tags: pubnub

I'm fairly new to PubNub. I've been using it to control a relatively simple IoT device.

A user interface allows a user to publish messages of the form `{ "desiredState": state }`.

Then, the actual device which is subscribed to the channel sets the state accordingly and publishes a new message back `{ "actualState": state }`.

Then both ends are aware if there is a difference between `actualState` and `desiredState`. It's not clear to me though, how I would leverage the PubNub APIs to retrieve the latest of each of those messages. So, for example, I want a single JSON object something like this:

```
{
  "desiredState": state1,
  "actualState": state2
}
```

In this case, `state1` would be the latest `"desiredState"` message and `state2` would be the latest `"actualState"` message.

I have looked into the [storage and playback mechanism](https://www.pubnub.com/products/storage-and-playback/), but I'm not sure that is the simplest way to go.

**What is an efficient PubNub solution for remembering the latest values for each of the possible keys I am publishing?**

Comment: Just a quick answer (I can elaborate if needed), if each device is only modifying its own state, then you can use BLOCKS and the KV store to get/set state there. Without BLOCKS, you can use Storage/Playback - when you publish a message it gets stored on that channel. Use history to get the last message and then publish again to store the new state. Let me know if you want to go into details on either of these strategies.